# php script won't run correctly in subdirectory coz of .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I can't run php script in subdirectory and i believe there's something wrong with .htaccess file.

my subfolder name is "crm".

and here's .htaccess code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # option to force redirect to ssl (https) - uncomment the two lines below
    # RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on    
    # RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    
    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.svg|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt|\.png|\.ttf|\.woff)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Can you please help me to fix this?

And when I try to get an image address from the subdirectory it thinks the image is on the root

Comment: How should we offer any help without you posting the content of that script? And telling us what "can't run" actually means exactly?

Comment: `.htaccess` is apache-specific.. it doesn't affect PHP in any way - I guess you meant "I cannot reach my PHP script from a browser due to .htaccess" (which relates to HTTP traffic)

Comment: What makes you think there is something wrong with the `.htaccess` file? (The `.htaccess` file looks fine, it should not affect any requests to physical (`.php`) files in a subdirectory.) What response are you getting when you try to request your PHP script in the subdirectory? "And when I try to get an image address from the subdirectory it thinks the image is on the root" - What do you mean by that?